# ftp file sharing

Tags: file, ftp, sharing

I want to write a client server program in linux which works like ftp, but I am unable to get or put the files from and to the server.
Please suggest any ideas to do it...

Comment: If you want something like ftp, why not just use ftp? That said - your question is very vague. You give no clue as to what programming language you are using, and you give no clue as to what is causing problems. Reading files from the file system? Opening network connections? etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... you didn't say which language you are using, and you didn't describe the problems you're getting. You didn't even explain what you have now, so it may be difficult to help you effectively.

However, I can point you to some resources which should be helpful for you:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt (the FTP spec)

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/ftp/ (Google Chrome's FTP implementation in modern C++. The most interesting file is probably ftp_network_transaction.cc)

http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/ (server-like FTP code in Python)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am using the combination of C and linux.Whenever I transfer a file using the get command the file is transferred but after the contents of the file lot of garbage is appended.
Also I am finding a problem in showing that a file is not present in the server to be transferred if the user gives a filename which is not available.